# Group homomorphism containing the trivial kernel only

Tags: group-homomorphism

Is it right to say that this is a group homomorphism and it only contains the trivial kernel?

$$\Phi : (\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}, ×) \longrightarrow (\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}, ×) : x \mapsto |x|$$

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{R}/0$ usually refers to the quotient space of $\mathbb{R}$ with $0$ (which is $\mathbb{R}$). I believe you want the slash to be in the other direction, like this: $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$ (which is the set of real numbers excluding zero).

Comment: There is a $\LaTeX$ keyword that produces the backslash notation called `\setminus`, which is convenient to avoid having to "escape" the backslash as used in $\LaTeX$ as a delimiter/escape character.

Comment: You're asking a few questions about the kernel of various potential homomorphisms lately. Are you sure you understand the definitions involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a homomorphism. But the kernel is not trivial, since $1$ and $(-1)$ are both in the kernel.